# Dynamic populating the html table with different json data on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to populate my html table with json data on button click based on the value specified by the variables at run time, its working fine for the first click on "go" button but latter its not working. I marked with the comment in the code till where its working .

```js
 var multicompanyUseCaseData="";
 var orderConditionData="";
 var orderTypeData="";

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#report").hide();
  $("#orderGraph").hide();
  $("#profitGraph").hide();
    //populate with json data on button click
  $("#go").click(function() {
    $("#orderGraph").show();
    $("#profitGraph").show();
    loadGraphOrderFilter();
    loadGraphProfitFilter();
    $("#report").show();
    $("#datatable > tbody > tr").remove();
   var e;
   if(document.getElementById("mcuc_selection"))
   {
    e=document.getElementById("mcuc_selection");
    multicompanyUseCaseData = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
   }
   if(document.getElementById("oc_selection"))
   {   
    e = document.getElementById("oc_selection");
    orderConditionData = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
   }
   if(document.getElementById("ot_selection"))
   {
    e = document.getElementById("ot_selection");
    orderTypeData = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
   }

          //At second click on button the code doesn't works after it.
   response1 = $.parseJSON(response1);


    $.each(response1, function (i, item) {
 if( item.useCase == multicompanyUseCaseData || item.orderCondition == orderConditionData || item.orderType == orderTypeData )
 {
        $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.orderId),
        $('<td>').text(item.purchaseId),
        $('<td>').text(item.shipmentId),
        $('<td>').text(item.useCase),
        $('<td>').text(item.orderCondition),
        $('<td>').text(item.orderType)).appendTo('#datatable');
 }
 

});

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var handleDataTableButtons = function() {};

        TableManageButtons = function() {
          "use strict";
          return {
            init: function() {
              handleDataTableButtons();
            }
          };
        }();

        $('#datatable').dataTable();
        $('#datatable-keytable').DataTable({
          keys: true
        });

        $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable();

        $('#datatable-scroller').DataTable({
          ajax: "js/datatables/json/scroller-demo.json",
          deferRender: true,
          scrollY: 380,
          scrollCollapse: true,
          scroller: true
        });

        var table = $('#datatable-fixed-header').DataTable({
          fixedHeader: true
        });

        TableManageButtons.init();
      });
   
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#myButton").click(function(e){
    $("#datatable").table2excel({
     name: "Excel Document Name",
     filename: "McosData",
     fileext: ".xls",
     exclude_img: true,
     exclude_links: true,
     exclude_inputs: true
    });
   });  
   });
  });
 });
```

```html
var response1 = '[{"orderId":"19", "purchaseId":"Alon", "shipmentId":"5", "useCase":"AGS", "orderCondition":"2", "orderType":"Customer" }';
response1 += ',{"orderId":"19", "purchaseId":"Alon", "shipmentId":"5", "useCase":"AGL", "orderCondition":"2", "orderType":"Customer" }';
response1 += ',{"orderId":"19", "purchaseId":"Alon", "shipmentId":"5", "useCase":"NAFN", "orderCondition":"2", "orderType":"Customer" }]';


//button click to load json data for the table
<button id="go" type="submit" value="Submit" >Go</button>


//table to be populated with json data
             <div id="report" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel" id="report_layout">
                  <div class="x_title">
       <button id="myButton">Excel</button>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Order Id</th>
      <th>Shipment Id</th>
      <th>Purchase Id</th>
      <th>Use Case</th>
      <th>Order Condition</th>
      <th>Order Type</th>
     </tr>
           </thead>


                      <tbody>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're parsing a JSON string on each click. After the first click, it's already been parsed, so `response1` isn't a valid JSON `string`, it is now an object. Change the name of your variable and it won't overwrite the string you're passing in.

```
var responseObject = $.parseJSON(response1);
$.each(responseObject, function (i, item) {
    // ...
});
```

[Attempted a plunker for organization only, won't work without libraries](http://plnkr.co/edit/DjWXoUnnCiktzczWCGXy?p=preview)

Comment: Its working some what u can say but the download of excel data on 'myButton" click is working only for first two click and same for the searching something on the table which i had created using textbox.